# Tranferring focus and clearing fields based on a barcode reading (VueJS)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm writing an app that runs on keyboard input but primarily as a barcode driven app. I'm having a hard time clearing some fields to reset the form after each button submission as well as refocusing on the correct field (the empty one)

Here's what it looks like
[image]

The Shipper ID doesn't clear unless I click that Black button or scan the barcode with value `*CloseShipper*`. It also loads empty the first time the page loads.

The Tracking # field clears and receives focus when I click the "Add To Batch" button or scan the barcode with value `*AddToBatch*`.

The App Barcode field clears immediately after I scan an App and adds it to an array that shows below it and receives focus right way to continue scanning non-stop until I finish the process by clicking or scanning the Add To Batch. (This part is working)

My problem is when I scan the `*AddToBatch*` barcode, nothing is happening. If I click it, the click event is being registered and it is clearing the fields that need to be cleared but the focus is still on the appbarcode. So, that's two problems separately.

Sorry I can't reproduce a working fiddle. Too many dependencies for it to work. So I'll post the relevant code here.

Template:

```
 <form class="uk-form-horizontal uk-margin-medium barcodefields">
    <div v-if="reset">
        <div class="uk-margin">
           <label 
              class="uk-form-label" 
              :for="_uid+'ctsinput'">
              Shipper ID
           </label>
           <div class="uk-form-controls">
              <input
                 class="uk-input"
                 :id="_uid+'ctsinput'"
                 name="shippernumber"
                 type="text"
                 maxlength="24"
                 :autofocus="'autofocus'"
                 v-focus
                 v-model.trim="shipperbarcode"
                 @input="runException"
              />
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="uk-margin">
           <label 
              class="uk-form-label" 
              :for="_uid+'ctsinput'">
              Tracking #
           </label>
           <div class="uk-form-controls">
              <input
                 class="uk-input"
                 :id="trackingNumber"
                 name="trackingnumber"
                 type="text"
                 maxlength="24"
                 v-model.trim="trackingbarcode"
                 @input="runException"
              />
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="uk-margin">
            <label 
               class="uk-form-label" 
               :for="_uid+'ctsinput'">
               App. Barcode #
            </label>
            <div class="uk-form-controls">
               <input
                 class="uk-input"
                 :id="_uid+'ctsinput'"
                 name="appbarcode"
                 type="text"
                 maxlength="24"
                 v-model.trim="applicationbarcode"
                 @change="addApplication"
               />
             </div>
         </div>

         <!-- This is the list of apps scanned -->
         <h5
            v-if="this.appList.length !== 0"
            class="heading-app-scanned"
            >Applications Scanned In This Batch</h5>
            <div
              v-if="this.appList.length !== 0"
              class="uk-card uk-card-secondary app-collection"
              >
              <div 
                 v-for="appItem in appList" 
                 :key="appItem.id" 
                 class="app-scanned-item">
                 <div class="uk-padding-small">
                   <label class="uk-form-label">Application #:</label>
                   <span class="uk-text">{{appItem}}</span>
                 </div>
                 <div class="uk-divider"></div>
              </div>
             </div>
       </div>
    </form>
```

In my scripts, besides all props and data, etc, here is the logic part:

```
  methods: {
  ...mapActions(["fetchBatches"]),
  // evaluating the value of the shipperbarcode and trackingbarcode
  runException: function(e) {
    this.shipperbarcode = this.shipperbarcode.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "");
    this.trackingbarcode = this.trackingbarcode.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "");
  },

  // evaluating what happens when an app is scanned
  addApplication: function(e) {
    let appBar = this.applicationbarcode;

    if (
      this.applicationbarcode === "*AddToBatch*" ||
      this.applicationbarcode === "*CloseShipper*"
    ) {
      this.applicationbarcode = "";
      return;
    } else {
      this.counter += 1;
    }
    //give access to the add to batch function to trigger the modal window and close batch
    this.addToBatch();
    // send the qualifying barcodes to an array and clear the field for the next scan
    this.appList.push(this.applicationbarcode);

    //give focus to the tracking number after a batch has been made
    document.addEventListener("change", function(appBar) {
      if (appBar === "*AddToBatch*") {
        this.appList = [];

        this.shipperbarcode = document.querySelector(
          "input[name=shippernumber]"
        ).value;
        this.trackingbarcode = "";

        let hasFocus = document.querySelector("input[name=trackingnumber]");
        hasFocus.focus();
        // after entering a new tracking number pass the focus to the barcode input
        if (hasFocus.value.length > 0) {
          hasFocus = document.querySelector("input[name=appbarcode]");
          hasFocus.focus();
        } else {
          hasFocus = document.querySelector("input[name=trackingnumber]");
          hasFocus.focus();
        }
      }
    });
    this.applicationbarcode = "";
    this.applicationbarcode = this.applicationbarcode.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "");
  },
  addedToBatch: function() {
    this.addToBatch("*AddToBatch*");
  },
  // When the add to batch button is scanned
  addToBatch: function(appBar) {
    // open the modal if the counter is above 25. This will be rewritten to read from server as the 25 can differ
    if (this.counter >= 25) {
      UIkit.modal("#closeBatchDialog").show();
    }

    // if the counter is > 0 show the close batch button
    if (this.counter > 0) {
      this.finishBatch = true;
    }

    // If the app barcode is Add to Batch barcode give shipper # input field the value it already has
    // and clear the tracking number field. ********** Must exist for click event
    if (appBar === "*AddToBatch*") {
      this.appList = [];

      this.shipperbarcode = document.querySelector(
        "input[name=shippernumber]"
      ).value;
      this.trackingbarcode = "";

      //give focus to the tracking number after a batch has been made
      let hasFocus = document.querySelector("input[name=trackingnumber]");
      hasFocus.focus();
      // after entering a new tracking number pass the focus to the barcode input
      if (hasFocus.value.length > 0) {
        hasFocus = document.querySelector("input[name=appbarcode]");
        hasFocus.focus();
      } else {
        hasFocus = document.querySelector("input[name=trackingnumber]");
        hasFocus.focus();
      }
    }
  },

  // if the close shipper barcode is scanned
  closeShipper: function(e) {
    // if the barcode for close shipper is scanned
    if (this.applicationbarcode === "*CloseShipper*") {
      // clear all fields
      this.appList = [];
      this.shipperbarcode = "";
      this.trackingbarcode = "";
      // give the shipper id field focus
      document.addEventListener("change", function() {
        let hasFocus = document.querySelector("input[name=shippernumber]");
        hasFocus.focus();
      });
    }
  },
  sendFocus: function(e) {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
      var input = e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() === "input";
      var form = e.target.form;
      if (e.key === "Enter" && input) {
        var index = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(form, e.target);
        form.elements[index + 1].focus();
      }
    });
  }
},
created() {
  let that = this;
  this.fetchBatches().then(function() {
    that.sendFocus();
  });
}
```

I commented as much as I could. The `addApplication` method is the one that validates that the barcode is a number or *AddToBatch*. If it's a number barcode, push it to the array as it is recognized as a normal barcode format. If it's reading *AddToBatch*, then clear the array (which later will put the array to the API), clear the tracking field and send the cursor to the tracking field to read a new tracking number

Any help will be very appreciated. I'm the only one here in this particular skillset and that sucks :( Thanks

P.S. No jQuery. ES6 preferably.

Answer (score 0):

You have an empty return inside application, thats why it behaves wierd on  "*AddToBatch*" condition, did you missed anything inside if condition or conditon should be like 
this.applicationbarcode === "*AddToBatch*" && this.applicationbarcode === "*CloseShipper*"

```
if (
      this.applicationbarcode === "*AddToBatch*" ||
      this.applicationbarcode === "*CloseShipper*"
    ) {
      this.applicationbarcode = "";
      return;
    } else {
      this.counter += 1;
    }
```

Comment: Tha return stops the "" blank read for when the barcode is not a number it replaces to blank (""). And it doesn't get added to the array

Comment: Basically, if the applicationbarcode is either AddToBatch or CloseShipper, clear the field and don't return the value of its read to the array. Else treat it as normal and counter up +1

Comment: Thanks for the clarification